# Spring Boot ClassNotFoundException org.springframework.core.metrics.ApplicationStartup when using Eureka Server

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, netflix-eureka

I was following this tutorial on Eureka https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-netflix-eureka, yesterday everything was working fine but today when I try to start my eureka-server I receive the following error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/metrics/ApplicationStartup
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:227)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:240)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292)
    at com.learning.lva.registryservice.RegistryServiceApplication.main(RegistryServiceApplication.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.metrics.ApplicationStartup
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 5 more
```

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.learning.lva</groupId>
    <artifactId>registry-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>registry-service</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>Greenwich.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

My spring version : 5.1.4.RELEASE

What I have tried:

Adding spring-context support dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Purging the maven local repository using: `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository`

I can't understand why is this happening since yesterday when I ran my application it was perfectly fine.

Comment: Are you running it from an ide? if yes try clearing the cache and reimporting dependencies

Comment: @ShamithaSilva Yes I am running from Intellij but I receive the same error even if I run the jar from the console after executing mvn clean install